# Unable to get response from api in IONIC android signed app for some devices

Tags: android, ajax, rest, ionic-framework

I am facing this issue with **signed android app** built using **IONIC 1**. For very few users I am facing this issue that app is unable to get any response from api and goes in error method of **ajax call**.

The surprising part is that if I generate an unsigned apk for the same code pointing to same server everything works smoothly on all devices.

**Technologies involved in app:** Rest api webservice, angularjs, IONIC 1, Cordova.

**Devices where faced this issue** as reported by users:- Samsung Duos,  OnePlus A3003 ; Android 7.0 ; Lenovo A6020a40 (android 5.1.1)

The error method value of params are as given below

data: null,
status :-1,
headers: undefined

Has anyone faced a similar issue wrt signed apk or with IONIC code?If so how did you resolve it.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yeah. 
After updating system web view component of the phone, the issue was resolved.

Comment: So you are saying that the fault is in the phone model? I am using old phone for testing.

Comment: Some old models and specifically phones which are not updated from a long time and hence issues in their system web view component.